# append or bind columns iteratively through a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe with 900 columns. I want to use tidyverse to append/bind columns in multiples of three (or another number). For example, append columns 2:3 to 1; columns 5:6 to 4, columns 8:9 to 7, and so on for the entire dataframe. Thus at the end I will have 300 columns, while keeping the name of the main column (where other columns have been appended to).

How do I do this? Thank you very much :)

Comment: you want to concatenate characters of 3 columns in 1 ?

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
# data
df = data.frame(matrix(1:27, ncol=9))
names(df) <- paste('Int', rep(1:3, each=3), 'A', rep(1:3, 3), sep='_')

n = 3
df %>% 
    # split the data frame into three data frames 
    split.default(rep(1:n, ncol(df) / n)) %>% 
    # rename and row bind the three data frames together
    map_df(
        ~ set_names(.x, names(df)[c(T, rep(F, n - 1))]) %>%
            tibble::rownames_to_column('gene')
    )

#  gene Int_1_A_1 Int_2_A_1 Int_3_A_1
#1    1         1        10        19
#2    2         2        11        20
#3    3         3        12        21
#4    1         4        13        22
#5    2         5        14        23
#6    3         6        15        24
#7    1         7        16        25
#8    2         8        17        26
#9    3         9        18        27
```

**More notes on `set_names`**: `c(T, rep(F, n - 1))` first create a vector as `c(T, F, F, ...)`, and so `names(df)[c(T, rep(F, n - 1))]` picks up a name every n elements due to R Cycling rule.

Or if you start from a matrix, you can reshape it with `array` function and desired shape:

```
m = matrix(1:27, ncol=9)
m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#[1,]    1    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25
#[2,]    2    5    8   11   14   17   20   23   26
#[3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27

array(m, c(nrow(m) * 3, ncol(m) / 3))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1   10   19
# [2,]    2   11   20
# [3,]    3   12   21
# [4,]    4   13   22
# [5,]    5   14   23
# [6,]    6   15   24
# [7,]    7   16   25
# [8,]    8   17   26
# [9,]    9   18   27
```

---

To keep the names, you can use `data.table::melt`:

```
library(data.table)
```

*Sample Data*:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(1:27, ncol=9))
names(df) <- paste('Int', rep(1:3, each=3), 'A', rep(1:3, 3), sep='_')
df
#  Int_1_A_1 Int_1_A_2 Int_1_A_3 Int_2_A_1 Int_2_A_2 Int_2_A_3 Int_3_A_1 Int_3_A_2 Int_3_A_3
#1         1         4         7        10        13        16        19        22        25
#2         2         5         8        11        14        17        20        23        26
#3         3         6         9        12        15        18        21        24        27

# create the patterns that group data frames    
cols <- paste0('Int_', seq_len(ncol(df) / 3), '_A')

# melt the data.table based on the column patterns and here you also get an id column telling
# you where the data comes from the 1st, 2nd or 3rd ..
setNames(melt(setDT(df), measure=patterns(cols)), c('id', cols))

#   id Int_1_A Int_2_A Int_3_A
#1:  1       1      10      19
#2:  1       2      11      20
#3:  1       3      12      21
#4:  2       4      13      22
#5:  2       5      14      23
#6:  2       6      15      24
#7:  3       7      16      25
#8:  3       8      17      26
#9:  3       9      18      27
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Very elegant and easy to follow solution. Can we keep the row names? Also, it will be nice if the column name of the "top" column can be kept as it is. Thank you.

Comment: How is your data frame named initially ? You might need `reshape / melt / dcast` for this if you want to keep the information from the original names.

Comment: Column names are something like this: Int_1_A_1, Int_1_A_2, Int_1_A_3, Int_2_A_1, Int_2_A_2, Int_2_A_3, Int_3_A_1, Int_3_A_2, Int_3_A_3, etc... So, after rowbind I will have Int_1_A_1, Int_2_A_1, Int_3_A_1, etc. Thanks

Comment: Thank you again. I am following your tidyverse approach. The code beautifully keeps the column names like I want, but still not getting the row names. My row names are actually gene names and I want to keep them. Thanks

Comment: Also, can you please explain map_df(~ set_names(.x, names(df)[c(T, rep(F, n - 1))]))

Comment: Added a note on `set_names`, and also since `dplyr::bind_rows` which `map_df` internally uses drop row names unfortunately, if you need to keep the row names information, you can create a new column based on the row names using a function like `tibble::rownames_to_column` and then bind them together, see the update.

Comment: Perfect. I can easily move the gene column around. Thank you so much. And can you please explain what you did in `map_df(~ set_names(.x, names(df)[c(T, rep(F, n - 1))]))`. This will help me to learn.

Comment: I added the explanation in the answer, see the bold highlight. Also to see how it works, take a look at the output of `(1:10)[c(T,F,F)]`.

Comment: Great. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sure. Glad it helps!

Answer (score 2):

A solution can be achieved using `tidyr::unite` and `tidyr::separate_rows`. The approach is to first unite columns in group of 3 and then use `tidyr::separate_rows` function to expand those in rows.

I have taken data created by `@Psidom` in his answer. Also, I should mention that `data.table::melt` based is most appropriate for problem. But one can explore different ideas using different approach.

```
library(tidyverse)
# data
df = data.frame(matrix(1:27, ncol=9))
names(df) <- paste('Int', rep(1:3, each=3), 'A', rep(1:3, 3), sep='_')

lapply(split(names(df),cut(1:ncol(df),3, labels = seq_len(ncol(df) / 3))),
       function(x){unite_(df[,x], paste(x[1],x[3], sep = ":"), x, sep = ",",
                               remove = TRUE)}) %>%
  bind_cols() %>%
  separate_rows(., seq_len(ncol(.)), sep = ",")

#   Int_1_A_1:Int_1_A_3 Int_2_A_1:Int_2_A_3 Int_3_A_1:Int_3_A_3
# 1                   1                  10                  19
# 2                   4                  13                  22
# 3                   7                  16                  25
# 4                   2                  11                  20
# 5                   5                  14                  23
# 6                   8                  17                  26
# 7                   3                  12                  21
# 8                   6                  15                  24
# 9                   9                  18                  27
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution:

```
df <- head(mtcars)[-1:-2] # 9 cols

df[(seq(df)-1) %% 3 == 0] <-
  lapply(split(seq(df), (seq(df)-1) %/% 3),
         function(x) apply(df[x], 1, paste, collapse="_"))
df <- df[(seq(df)-1) %% 3 == 0]
df
#                           disp            wt    am
# Mazda RX4          160_110_3.9  2.62_16.46_0 1_4_4
# Mazda RX4 Wag      160_110_3.9 2.875_17.02_0 1_4_4
# Datsun 710         108_93_3.85  2.32_18.61_1 1_4_1
# Hornet 4 Drive    258_110_3.08 3.215_19.44_1 0_3_1
# Hornet Sportabout 360_175_3.15  3.44_17.02_0 0_3_2
# Valiant           225_105_2.76  3.46_20.22_1 0_3_1
```

Comment: Thanks. This concatenates the columns instead of row binding them! This is not what I want. The solution from @Psidom works almost perfect except that it drops the row names, unfortunately.

Comment: I'll edit when I have a computer in front of me, it's an easy fix